# Why not receiving request body as a dictionary - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm using manual built form (not the `Forms.form` or `ModelForms.form`) in Django.

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="tabs-contents">
            <div id="infos" class="tab-content">

                <form action="/page/" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="infos-form-content">
                        <div class="infos-row-1">
                            <input id="field1" type="text" value="" name="field1">
                            <input id="field2" type="text" value="" name="field2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos-row-2">
                            <input id="field3" type="date" value=""
                                name="field3">
                        </div>
           ...
           ...
                    </div>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>
                   </form>
                  </div>
                 </div>                        
             </div>
```

And it contains also dynamic input fields (created by JavaScript).
When I check the `request.body` type in the view (after decoding of course `request.body.decode('utf-8')`) I find it's a string and not a dictionary. Why is that happening ? And how to receive the form data in dict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.body` does not return a dictionary. You have to specify the type of request in the view to get the dictionary e.g. `request.GET` or `request.POST`.

Also, note that these are actually not dictionaries, but objects that act like dictionaries (more specifically [django.http.request.QueryDict](http://django.http.request.QueryDict)), so there are some differences.

To get your posted data and loop over it, you can do the following :

```
data = request.POST
for key in data:
    print(f'{key}: {data[key]}')
```

Comment: Yes, I checked like that `if request.method == 'POST'`. But I could load the reauest:body with json.loads() in other request and then access to fields values like this : `body['field']`.

Comment: That is not what I meant. `request.POST` has the dictionary. So, if you wanted to grab the value of input field1, you would use `request.POST['field1']`. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful for me.